# Using JQuery .click and .toggle to contract and expand a concentric circle

Tags: jquery, html, css, user-interface

I'm trying to expand and contract a circle on another circle with the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#inner-circle").click(function(){
    $("#inner-circle").toggle(
      function(){
        $(this).transition({ "height":'1.0em',
                             "width":'1.0em',
                             "margin-top":'3.2em',
                             "margin-left":'3.2em'
                            }, 1000);
      },
      function(){
        $(this).transition({ "height":'1.875em',
                             "width":'1.875em',
                             "margin-top":'3.75em',
                             "margin-left":'3.75em'
                            }, 1000);
      }
      )});
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#data1").hover(function(){
    $("#data1").toggle(
      function(){
        $(this).css({"background":"blue"});
      },
      function () {
        $(this).css({"background":"red"});
      },
      function () {
        $(this).css({"background":"orange"});
      });
  });
});
```

But the actual behavior exhibited is definitely not what I am looking for (and, strangely, varies whether I run it through JSFiddle or as an HTML file through my browser(Firefox). Here is the JSFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/Ue9pu/

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation, jquery.toggle() is used to show/hide elements, it does not work by toggling between two functions as you seem to intend (so what you were doing was toggling the visibility of the element, toggle comes with a shrinking animation before it hides and that is what you were seeing).  Also, jquery.transition() doesn't exist, you probably wanted jquery.animate() instead.

I've made an update to your code here http://jsfiddle.net/Ue9pu/4/.  I've changed it so the toggling is done internally via a boolean value that alternates instead.  Now you just need to get the animation right.

```
var tog = false;
$("#inner-circle").click(function () {
    if (tog) {
        $(this).animate({
            "height": '1.0em',
                "width": '1.0em',
                "margin-top": '3.2em',
                "margin-left": '3.2em'
        }, 1000);
    } else {
        $(this).animate({
            "height": '1.875em',
                "width": '1.875em',
                "margin-top": '3.75em',
                "margin-left": '3.75em'
        }, 1000);
    }
    tog = !tog;
});
```